# Html tagging elements with custom tags instead of using classes

Tags: html, css

Instead of using the standard class="someclass", I deviated from this pattern and "tagged" the div thus:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
div[tag1]
{
background-color:Red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div tag1>test</div>
<div>test</div>
</body>
</html>
```

What are the drawbacks of this approach (besides the obvious fact that it might confuse some developers)? 
Will it work in any browser? (I checked FF, IE and Chrome - it worked in all of them)
To me, it looks more concise than using "class".
Thanks!

Comment: this looks like you want to create the wheel new.... everyone uses class or id, so why you want to come up with a new way? and by the way... i guess you will get problems if you start using jquery / bootstrap and stuff like this

Comment: Agreed, i dont see why you would want to do this.

Comment: Actually, it works with jquery too.
I want this mainly because it takes less space (you don't use the 'class' word, which, with the = and parenthesis eats up 8 characters).
Thanks for your replies

Answer (score 1):

I see a few drawbacks to your approach

**Specificity**: All attributes in the element, with exception to the ID, are parsed as classes. By choosing to go with `<div someAtt>`, this is always going to have the specificity of a class: 0,0,1,0.

**Selectors**: You don't make shorter selectors:

The `class` of an element is **also** an attribute. You could select an element that has a class like so:

```
[class="tag1"]{
 color:red;
 }
```

This, in fact, is the "normal" way to select an element with an attribute which has a value. The manner in which we select classes is more of a shorthand for the above rule:

```
.tag1{
 color:red
 }
```

Because you're proposing a custom attribute, your selector will be:

```
[tag1]{
color:red
}
```

If you're counting characters, the "longhand" attribute selector takes the most space and the class selector the least. You're not making a stylesheet shorter with your approach. Your selector will always be longer by at least one character.  Is this a huge deal? No. But it will be over time, and now you have to train someone who takes over your stylesheet on your approach.

**Extensibility**: Another issue with adding an invalid attribute to your markup is extensibility. Your goal should be extensible markup and CSS, so you want a pattern that's reusable. if you're going to have tag1, tag2, etc, this isn't an extensible pattern.

How do you plan on dealing with reusable styles? What you're saying is that `<div tag1 tag2 tag3 tag4>` could happen at some point in the future. How do you plan on styling that?

```
div[tag1][tag2][tag3][tag4]{
color:red;
border-color:red;
outline-color: red;
background-color: red;
}

[tag1]{
color:red
}
[tag2]{
border-color:orange
}
[tag3]{
outline-color:yellow
}
```

I see `tag` as a reusable attribute which can accept a changing value:

```
<div tag="one">
```

Which results in this selector:

```
   [tag="one"]{
   color: green
   }
```

Which ultimately means you have replicated the "class" approach, but with a longer selector and no means to a shorthand (like the `.` that's the same as `[class=""]`.

**Valid Markup**: The next issue I see in your approach is that you're using invalid attributes. In HTML5, you can use the `data-*` approach to pretty much create whatever attributes you want in a somewhat normalized pattern. But invalid attributes such as `tag1` could throw off any HTML validators. Additionally, I don't know how screen readers or other accessibility devices might struggle with invalid or unknown attributes.

**The Neighborly Way**: The final issue that I see is more philosophical.  We get a heck of a lot more freedom and flexibility in HTML and CSS than in other development languages. Web browsers are much, *much* more forgiving of mistakes that we make in HTML and CSS than compiled languages. We shouldn't equate the freedom to be different to the wisdom of following standards and best practices.

Answer (score 0):

The only drawback I can think of is that you lock your css to a tag type. ie with class you could do:

```
<div class="alignRight"> Some thing </div>
<table class="alignRight">table data</table>
```

Your approach does not allow for this. Apart from this I don't think it's any technical issue with using your approach.

Comment: Thanks, in my markup I mostly use "divs" anyways so that does not present any problems

Comment: I guess there will be some purists that will not like this, and they have a point, as you only complicate your code for no gain. Not sure why you think it's a good thing to have 8 chars less in your html, but if that is most important to you, go right ahead =)